# Jmeter Issue in recording HTTPS site

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, keystore

I am encountering an strange issue while recording a HTTPS site.
The error code is :-
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificate s(Unknown Source) at I have tried the following after referring to different posts in google:-

1. Updated JDK to JDK7
2. Exported the Certficate of the Website in crt,der and p7c
3. Imported the certificate to cacerts of jre7/lib/security

I am selecting HTTP 4 client for recording.
If I use JAVA, the error code is :-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificat e(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(U nknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHands hake(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unkn own Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unkn own Source) at I reinstalled JDK7.
The error code has now changed to :-
Secure Connection Failed
Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
(Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see an explicit question per-se in your question (you were just stating that you are encountering an strange issue while recording a HTTPS site).

If your site works in Chrome you can try bypassing JMeter's HTTP proxy entirely by using the JMeter Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi

BlazeMeter is a paid service but you can use the chrome extension as much as you want with their free account.